# How to insert empty string instead of null in PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, null, constraints

I'm refactoring the code, from `mysql` extension to `pdo's`. Existing `db` schema is such way that for almost all columns in 100 pulse tables are having `NOT NULL` constraint. Due to this constraint I'm very often facing following error while `inserting` and `updating` the data.

`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'some-column-name' cannot be null`

Obligations:

1. Its not possible to change db schema i,e removing NOT NULL constraint.
2. Its difficult to check whether value is null or not before inserting for each and every column.

So I'm looking for a generic solution where empty string is inserted instead of `NULL` that will be addressed for all `PDO` statements. I'm using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472677/1111502) `PDO` helper class.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you're inserting the data?

Answer (score 1):

When you declare your column, do it with `NOT NULL DEFAULT ''`. This way, MySQL will replace a NULL value with an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as I mentioned in "obligations" section, its not possible to change db schema.

Answer (score 0):

After searching in web finally come with following solution by extending `PDOStatement` class. Remember this credits goes `SE` and other sources in web.

```
class CustomPDOStatement extends PDOStatement
{

public $removeNulls = FALSE;
public $dbh;

protected function __construct($dbh)
{
    $this->dbh = $dbh;
}

public function execute($input_parameters = null)
{
    if ($this->removeNulls === TRUE && is_array($input_parameters)) {
        foreach ($input_parameters as $key => $value) {
            if (is_null($value)) {
                $input_parameters[$key] = '';
            }
        }
    }

    return parent::execute($input_parameters);
}

public function bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR)
{
    if ($this->removeNulls === TRUE && is_null($value)) {
        $value = '';
    }

    return parent::bindValue($parameter, $value, $data_type);
}

public function bindParam($parameter, &$variable, $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR, $length = null, $driver_options = null)
{
    if ($this->removeNulls === TRUE && is_null($variable)) {
        $variable = '';
    }

    parent::bindParam($parameter, $variable, $data_type, $length, $driver_options);
 }
}
```

And while inserting or updating I'm doing like this

```
$insertUser = $pdoDB->prepare("INSERT INTO users (id,email,name,age) VALUES (:id, :email, :name, :age)");
$insertUser->removeNulls = TRUE;
$insertUser->bindValue(':id', $id);
$insertUser->bindValue(':email', $email);
$insertUser->bindValue(':name', $name);
$insertUser->bindValue(':age', $age); // May be NULL
$insertUser->execute();
```

To avoid too many checks for `removeNulls` bind values by passing `array` as argument to `execute()`.

Got this idea by referring following sources

1. [Extending PDO class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1472677/1111502).
2. [Extending PDOStatement class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3431305/1111502) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11825907/1111502).
3. Other sources of web.